# Mirror photo directories and reduce file size

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I backup our family photos to my home Ubuntu 14.04 server, to a Samba directory at */srv/photos*. I want to be able to view them by visiting a web page, to browse through them, and have created a php page to do just that. Rather than using the actual 3-5Mb photos themselves though, which would be very slow, I want to use Imagemagick to create 200-300Kb copies in a folder (/var/www/album for instance), and then point my php page at that.

I want to create a script which will recreate the folder structure of */srv/photos/* in */var/www/album*, and also run Imagemagick on each photo within each sub-folder to reduce their file size. In the end I want to end up with a folder structure in */var/www/album* mirroring that of */srv/photos*, with all jpg's of a reduced size.

I've seen commands which will mirror the folder structure:

```
$ find -type d -exec mkdir -p /target-folder/{} \;
```

and Imagemagick will reduce file quality & size (some experimentation required...):

```
convert holiday_pic.jpg reduced_holiday_pic.jpg -quality 50
```

It feels like I would need some sort of array to do this... for each jpg in */srv/photos/folder_X*, convert and save it to */var/www/album/folder_X*...

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` for synchronizing files and folders structure and then `mogrify` to lower files quality.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\t\n'

files=`rsync -rvu /srv/photos/ /var/www/album/ |grep -i jpg` && cd /var/www/album
mogrify -quality 50 $files
```

`Mogrify` is the same as `convert` but it is overwriting changed files (in this example after synchronizing in your *album* folder)
`IFS` is set for files and folders with spaces

```
rsync options:

-r be recursive - for folders structure
-v verbose - tell what you are doing 
-u update - skip files that are newer on the receiver
```

---

When there are different file types in your *photos* folder you can tell rsync to synchronize only `jpg` files by adding this to rsync command:

```
--include '*/' --include '*.jpg' --exclude '*'
```